# How to properly use command substitution as argument of a command with a space in file list?

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a file called FILES with the content :

```
/path/to/something
/path/to/something/else
/path/to/something/else/with/a space
/path/to/something/else/again
```

If I try to use command substitution like this : `head -n 1 $(cat FILES)`

I will have :

```
head: cannot open 'a' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open 'space' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Using escape character `\` or delimiters `""` or `''` aren't solving this issue. (I don't know why...)

What is the proper way to do this ?

***EDIT :*** Apparently my problem is simpler than I thought.
This is working :

```
head "a space" no_space
```

But this is not :

```
FILES='"a space" no_space'; echo $FILES; head $FILES
```

Here it is seen as 3 files : `"a` , `space"` and `no_space`.
So... How to ask the shell not to ignore the delimiters ? (or escape char)

***EDIT2*** :

Found a solution with :

```
while read line; do head "$line"; done < FILES
```

Does someone have something without using loops ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the first row of each file defined in your `FILES` file?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon Yes, every line as separate arguments.

Comment: you're close, but you need to also quote the variables.  e. g. `head "$FILE"`; `echo "$FILE"`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti That's an easy fix indeed... if I had only one argument. I added an EDIT with an example of the problem.

Comment: Quoting is only interpreted on _input_ to the shell, not on the result of command substitution or parameter/variable expansion. If you want to use a variable in bash (but not some other shells) you need an _array_: `readarray -t F <FILES; head -n1 "${F[@]}"`

Answer (score 4):

The correct solution to get each line (ended in a newline character) into an array that allows spaces (but not NULs or newlines) in the file names is:

```
$ readarray -t files <FILES

$ printf '<%s>\n' "${files[@]}"
</path/to/something>
</path/to/something/else>
</path/to/something/else/with/a space>
</path/to/something/else/again>
```

Then you can use each value from `"${files[0]}"` up to the last index.

Please quote each argument to avoid the effects of splitting as performed by the shell.

If all you want to do is to get the first line of each file listed inside FILES, you can do:

```
$ readarray -t files <FILES
$ head -n1 "${files[@]}"
first line on first file
first line on second file
...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

It's should be very useful if you use before the scripts: `set -f`.
Thanks to ikkachu for that suggestion.

**Solution 1**:

Setting `IFS=$'\n'`:

```bash
IFS=$'\n' ; head -1  $(cat data)
```

**Solution 2**:

Another possible solution is adding double quotes between the paths defined in `FILES`:

```
"/path/to/something"
"/path/to/something/else"
"/path/to/something/else/with/a space"
"/path/to/something/else/again"
```

And with the help of `xargs` get the result:

```bash
cat FILES | xargs head -n1
#or
xargs head -n1 < FILES
#or
xargs head -n1 <<< $(cat FILES)
```

Comment: It's one solution yes, but it seems to be very overkill, isn't there a cleaner way to do that ? :(

Comment: I'm not sure , I could give a try with another way. (With export IFS should work because ifs is usually set with \n)

Comment: Apparently, the delimiters and escape char are ignores when inside a variable. (I made an edit on the initial post.)

Comment: @bobdylan I edited the answer with another solution.

Comment: You don't need to export because wordsplitting is done in the shell; you only need to set IFS -- and subsequently set it back, most easily by confining the setting to a subshell with parentheses.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I thought that, but If don't export the variable then the command doesn't work, I don't really why.

Comment: `( IFS=$'\n'; printf "%s\n" $(cat files) )` works fine (without the export). But if you rely on word splitting, note that you also get globbing, so files with names containing `*?[]` might cause surprises. `set -f` to disable that.

Comment: @ilkkachu I tried your command with and without parentheses and it worked. My error is that I was trying to set `IFS='\n'` without the comma: `IFS=$'\n' head -n 1 $(cat data2)` and therefore it didn't work.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 you are right, my bad! a little mistake I had.